# How to pause and resume IO tasks?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, blocking

A function that does a task on IO thread.

eg:

```kotlin
suspend fun fx() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val p = Path("""D:\Games\Eg.7z""")
    val p2 = Path("""D:\New folder\Eg.7z""")
    p.copyTo(p2) // takes a while to complete
    Unit
}
```

I want to pause the IO operation from the `Dispatchers.Main` keyPressed event, and resume it at will.

How do I pause and resume a coroutine task?

**Update:**
From the answer, it seems it's out of scope of Coroutine. So, how else we can pause & resume IO tasks if not using coroutines?

Comment: I'd look into lower level APIs like FileInputStream that allow you to copy bytes at a time and try doing that in an loop that could be exited if the coroutine was canceled ("pause"). You'd track the bytes copied and then "resume" by restarting the copy operation from where you left off.

Comment: You _might_ be able to do this by manually reimplementing `copy` to include a call to `yield` every so often.  That's probably as good as you can get.  You may not even be able to do this at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With more reading and testing, I've managed to make a simple version. Edit for folder and specific use cases.

```kotlin
enum class TaskSwitch {
    Running, Paused, Cancelled,
}

fun incrementalCopy(
    source: Path,
    destination: Path,
    switch: MutableStateFlow<TaskSwitch>,
    deleteIncomplete: Boolean = true,
    bufferSize: Int = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE
) = flow {

    var shouldDelete = false

    var bytesCopied = 0L
    source.inputStream().use { inputStream ->
        destination.outputStream().use { outputStream ->

            val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
            var bytes = inputStream.read(buffer)
            while (bytes >= 0) {
                when (val taskSwitch = switch.value) {
                    TaskSwitch.Running -> {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes)
                        bytesCopied += bytes
                        emit(bytesCopied)

                        bytes = inputStream.read(buffer)
                    }

                    TaskSwitch.Paused -> {
                        //Suspends until it's not in Paused anymore
                        switch.first {
                            it != taskSwitch
                        }
                    }

                    TaskSwitch.Cancelled -> {
                        shouldDelete = deleteIncomplete
                        break
                    }
                }
                yield()
            }
        }
    }

    if (shouldDelete) {
        destination.deleteIfExists()
    }

}.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)


fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val sourceFile = Path("D:\\Games\\Age-Of-Empires-II-HD.rar")
    val targetFile = Path("D:\\New folder\\A\\B\\Age-Of-Empires-II-HD.rar")
    targetFile.parent.createDirectories()
    val switch = MutableStateFlow(TaskSwitch.Running)
    launch {
        incrementalCopy(sourceFile, targetFile, switch).collectLatest {
            println(it)
        }
        println("Finished!")
    }

    delay(5000L)
    switch.update {
        TaskSwitch.Paused
    }
    println("Paused")
    delay(10000L)
    println("Running")
    switch.update {
        TaskSwitch.Running
    }

//    delay(1000L)
//    switch.update {
//        TaskSwitch.Cancelled
//    }
//    println("Canceled")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood what coroutines allow you to do.

Most of the properties of coroutines are cooperative. If you're using a blocking operation that doesn't support suspension, coroutines cannot help with it.

What coroutines can help with is offloading the blocking I/O to a different thread more easily (using `withContext`), but that's what you already did.

Comment: I'm currently working on a FileManager project. Can you suggest me link or guides to pause & resume IO opeations? If not using coroutines, how else this can be achived?